# Take the audio from a youtube video

Tags: java, audio, youtube-api

Is it possible to retrieve only the audio from a youtube video using the java youtube api?

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to [How do I programmatically extract the audio from a YouTube video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030557/how-do-i-programmatically-extract-the-audio-from-a-youtube-video).

The top answer there is:

> Writing an application for this might
>   be overkill. Existing tools already do
>   a pretty good job, and it's hard to
>   beat their simplicity:
>
> ```
> wget http://www.youtube.com/get_video.php?video_id=...
> ```
>
> |
>         ffmpeg -i - audio.mp3
>
> All done!
>
> If your application needs to do
>   something special with the audio
>   afterwards, it would make sense to
>   write an app for that part. But for
>   just getting the audio out, shelling
>   out to ffmpeg will be a lot easier.

Kudos to [John Feminella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75170/john-feminella) for the answer.

Comment: Well this isn't exactly what I need, but it's my fault because I've not been precise. I'm working on  building a RIA for a school project and I'm using the Echo Nest Api to obtain playlist based on song similarity. I need other api to obtain the mp3 knowing the name of the song. I have to do it when the request is done so i need something different. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53 libav-tools

youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 4 http://youtu.be/oRJ0FaOIIbM
```

Comment: Hmm, does that not self explaining?:)

Comment: youtube-dl is cool. downloaded the whole playlist easily. It is on github